# Change position of input to call a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, sympy, cnf

This is my code :

```
from sympy import symbols, Equivalent
from sympy.logic.boolalg import to_cnf as fnc, Implies, to_cnf
from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, y, z


def eq(a, b):
    return fnc(Equivalent(a, b), True)

inr = str(input('Enter formula: '))
x = ' '
for i in inr:
     #print(inr[inr.index(i-2)])
     if i == '>':
         i = '>>'
         x += i
     elif i == '=':

         print(i)
         i = 'Equivalent'
         x += i

     else:
         x += i

print(fnc(x, True))
```

Instead of `input =(a,b)` to call `Equivalent function` i want to input `(a=b)`. How can I do that?
I have tried to controlling the element before and next of `=` and add it to `Equivalent` function  when you enter (a=b) the output should be `(a|~b)&(b|~a)` but it does not work.

```
i= sympy.Equivalent(symbols((inr[inr.index(i) - 1])), symbols(inr[inr.index(i) + 1]))
```

Comment: `str(input('Enter formula: '))` Uh?

Comment: user5173426 nope! the input is linked to a function if i enter =(a,b) it work but what i want is to enter (a=b) to call the function

Comment: so when you enter (a=b) the output should be?

Comment: @user5173426 it should be (a | ~b) & (b | ~a)

Comment: And when you enter =(a,b) you get the output: (a | ~b) & (b | ~a). Not Equivalent(a,b)?

Comment: Sorry i edited my answer yes that's what i want when i enter (a=b) the output should be (a | ~b) & (b | ~a)

Comment: @user5173426 what should i do ??

Comment: Okay. let me see this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, based on your Sample I/O which was:

***IN***: so when you enter (a=b) the output should be? – user5173426

***OUT***:  it should be (a | ~b) & (b | ~a) – Yacine Benatia

I made a few changes to your existing code:

```
from sympy import symbols, Equivalent
from sympy.logic.boolalg import to_cnf as fnc, Implies, to_cnf
from sympy.abc import a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, v, w, x, y, z


def eq(a, b):
    return fnc(Equivalent(a, b), True)

inr = str(input('Enter formula: '))
x = ' '
# get the part of the formula/string before =
y = inr.rsplit('=', 1)[0]
# get the part of the formula/string after =
z = inr.rsplit('=', 1)[1]
for i in inr:
     if i == '>':
         i = '>>'
         x += i
     elif i == '=':
         i = 'Equivalent'
         x = i
     elif i != ')':
         x += y
         x += ','
         x +=  z
     # print(x)

print(fnc(x, True))
```

OUTPUT:

[image: OUT]

Comment: Thank's a lot ,But how about if i enter a longer formula like  `(a>b)&(c=d)`                   it should be `(b | ~a) & (c | ~d) & (d | ~c)`
i think the example work only for (a=b)

Comment: The question was only about the specific problem, please ask another question with the detail problem!

Comment: What i want is that (x=y) work on all formula input,please can you help me?

Comment: No, please do not edit this question. You should ask another question with formulas being provided that you want the output for. and mark this one accepted if it helped solving the specific `(a=b)` problem. Thank you!

Comment: thank you for you help ,no problem i will mark it.Please can you continue to solve my problem.

Comment: Sure. Just ask another question, provide all the input formulas and expected outputs!